# View/log raw SOAP requests/responses using System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: .net, soap

I have a SOAP web service in .NET which uses:
 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol

How can I get the raw SOAP request/response XML that's getting sent over HTTP so that I can log the incoming/outgoing requests?

Note: I am *not* looking for an answer like "use Wireshark" or "use a HTTP sniffer". I want a way to *get the raw SOAP request/response as a string within my application* so that I can log it to a file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need custom [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) - there is a sample which shows how to get and save a message.